# div keeps moving when div next to it is removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making this windows 8 metro styled website and when you click one of the squares it bounces up with jquery .slideUp(). When it is slid up, the square next to it jumps in it's place, which is not what I want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".blok").click(function() {
    $(this).slideUp(1200, "easeOutBounce");
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.menu {
  height: 8%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #363636;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
}
.inhoud {
  height: 84%;
  width: 100%;
}
.blok {
  background-color: #EC1D25;
  display: flex;
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}
#blokGroot {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #2D89EF;
}
#blokMiddel {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #1E7145;
}
#blokKlein1 {
  height: 50%;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #7E3878;
}
#blokKlein2 {
  height: 50%;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #DA532C;
}
.footer {
  height: 8%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  background-color: #363636;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<!--Dit laadt het Raleway lettertype: -->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!--Dit laadt jQuery: -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<!--Dit laadt jQueryui: -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>


<!--Dit is de header: -->
<div class="menu">
  MAX
</div>


<!--Dit is alle inhoud emt de 4 vakken: -->
<div class="inhoud">

  <div class="blok" id="blokGroot">
    <a href="#" id="overMij-link">
      <img src="SVG/overMij.svg" alt="Over mij" height="150">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="blok" id="blokMiddel">
    <a href="#" id="informatica-link">
      <img src="SVG/informatica.svg" alt="Informatica" height="150">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="blok" id="blokKlein1">
    <a href="#" id="muziek-link">
      <img src="SVG/muziek.svg" alt="Muziek" height="150">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="blok" id="blokKlein2">
    <a href="#" id="hobbies-link">
      <img src="SVG/hobbies.svg" alt="Hobbies" height="150">
    </a>
  </div>

</div>


<!--Dit is de footer: -->
<div class="footer">
  (c) 2015
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and replace the marker I left with the information that is missing.

Comment: Add a placeholder block to replace each block you slide out.

Comment: After a block slides out, should something else show up in its place?

Comment: @LGSon yes, i want it to sort of reveal some text if you know what i mean

Comment: @Candy_In_Mah_Van I will do a smaller update soon to my answer that shows an idea for that.

Comment: @LGSon thank you very much, looking forward to your input

Comment: @Candy_In_Mah_Van Updated my answer with a way how you could do.

Comment: @Candy_In_Mah_Van If one of the answers solved your question it would be good if you choosed to accept the one that did, so future users will see which choice you made.

Answer (score 0):

A wrapper in each `.blok` would be one solution here, where you slide the `.wrapblok` instead of the `.blok`.

To control the display of `.blokwrap` and `.bloktext`, you can use `float:` or `position:` and when you slide out image, text could slide up or just be "behind".

CSS

```
.blok {
  overflow: hidden;   /* make blok no scroll and have bloktext scroll content */
}
.blokwrap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  etc...
}
.bloktext {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;  /* make it scroll might be good if content is big */
  etc...
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="blok" id="blokGroot">
  <div class="blokwrap">
    <a href="#" id="overMij-link">
      <img src="SVG/overMij.svg" alt="Over mij" height="150">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="bloktext">
    Here you can have some text etc...
  </div>
</div>

etc...
```

Here is a quick sample to show how it works, where I altered the "blokKlein1" item only and some of your css.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".blokwrap").click(function() {
    $(this).slideUp(1200, "easeOutBounce");
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.menu {
  height: 8%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #363636;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
}
.inhoud {
  height: 84%;
  width: 100%;
}
.blok {
  background-color: #EC1D25;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

.blokwrap, .bloktext {
  background-color: #EC1D25;
  display: flex;
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

#blokKlein1 .blokwrap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #7E3878;
}

#blokKlein1 .bloktext {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #000;
}

#blokGroot {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #2D89EF;
}
#blokMiddel {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #1E7145;
}
#blokKlein1 {
  height: 50%;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #7E3878;
}
#blokKlein2 {
  height: 50%;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #DA532C;
}
.footer {
  height: 8%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  background-color: #363636;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<!--Dit laadt het Raleway lettertype: -->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!--Dit laadt jQuery: -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<!--Dit laadt jQueryui: -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>


<!--Dit is de header: -->
<div class="menu">
  MAX
</div>


<!--Dit is alle inhoud emt de 4 vakken: -->
<div class="inhoud">

  <div class="blok" id="blokGroot">
    <a href="#" id="overMij-link">
      <img src="SVG/overMij.svg" alt="Over mij" height="150">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="blok" id="blokMiddel">
    <a href="#" id="informatica-link">
      <img src="SVG/informatica.svg" alt="Informatica" height="150">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="blok" id="blokKlein1">
    <div class="blokwrap">
      <a href="#" id="muziek-link">
        <img src="SVG/muziek.svg" alt="Muziek" height="150">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="bloktext">
        Some sample text...
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="blok" id="blokKlein2">
    <a href="#" id="hobbies-link">
      <img src="SVG/hobbies.svg" alt="Hobbies" height="150">
    </a>
  </div>

</div>


<!--Dit is de footer: -->
<div class="footer">
  (c) 2015
</div>
```

Comment: i tried it the way you described here but it doesnt work, would you mind specifying what the etc... would be?

Comment: @Candy_In_Mah_Van Added a sample to my answer, showing how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting there, just without the Jquery functions.

I have tried nesting an absolutely positioned div in the the divs, the functions all set both the outer and inner divs display to "none" though.

Here i have added a class with css visibility, and it works, just not with animation. I have tried to add a css class on click, i have tried a vanilla JS code to imitate slideToggle, but no luck.
This is kinda near a solution, i would know if the whole Html would be rearranged, but i get stuck here. Its a start, though.

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/KdeOpB

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".blok").click(function() {


$(this).toggleClass("newClass");
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is something, works, but few issues.
I have added the following element and placed it outside the viewport:

```
#blokGroot2 {
position:absolute;
margin-left:-101%;
height: 100%;
width: 50%;
background-color: blue;
}
```

Then, on click its animated to fly into the screen sideways with the animate method.

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/KdeOpB

This works perfectly fine, the other divs stay in place.

Now i have added another div the middle sized, and do the same to it, it reacts as it is supposed to, but its not placed exactly over the original "blokmiddel", i dont know why exactly.The 2 small divs are not fixed to the bottom entirely. But this should be easy to fix.
Another thing is, if you click on the blokmiddel, the blookgrot will fade out as well, this is an issue where i am not sure how to resolve, maybe the propagation/bubbling have to be fixed. I am curious about this myself.